# How Filter Data for Indicators with Moving Averages?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i'ts possible using a filter dates to reduce the calculation time?
Here there's a script that select 2 date and highlight this period. What im trying to do is plotting an `ta.ema` only for this selected period, avoid every other calculations.

(i think this is only possible in part. for example an `ta.ema` with 20 lenght using the 20 past values to calcualate but dont plotting them)

any way plotting only the highlighted period is a big forward jump to increase calculation power and avoiding other values not interested.

here the script:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Session Range Test", overlay=true)

c_startBacktest = input.time(timestamp('01 May 2022 00:00 +0000'),  'Start Date')
c_endBacktest   = input.time(timestamp('01 Jan 2023 00:00 +0000'),  'End Date')

backtest(int _start, int _end) => 
    session         = na(time(timeframe.period))
    backtestRange   = time >= _start and time <= _end

o_sessionActive = backtest(c_startBacktest, c_endBacktest)

bgcolor(o_sessionActive ? color.new(color.black,95) : na, title = "Session Active Background Fill")
plot(ta.ema(close,20))
```

[image: Example of the script that select a period time]
Someone solved this trouble? Assuming that its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any reason to think that calculating an EMA between only two timestamps will make your script take a lot longer to load?

To display your EMA only during the two timestamps, I believe you already know the solution

I recommend calculating the EMA at every candle and only displaying the parts you're interested in
Otherwise, you'll get some warning messages in orange from the Pine compiler strongly recommending you to calculate the EMA at every candle.

```
my_ema = ta.ema(close,20)
plot(o_sessionActive ? my_ema : na)
```